# What is the correct way to transfer Windows data from an external drive to a Linux system?

Tags: linux, windows, backup, file-transfer, rsync

I currently have Windows on my computer, and I am planning on switching to Linux.  Before making such a change, one first needs to back up Windows data.  After installing Linux, one would transfer the backed up data.  I was wondering what the correct way is to transfer the backed up data to Linux.

I believe the following procedure is correct.  However, before I try this, I want to check with others in this community.

I believe the first step would be to create a backup of Windows data, using a backup wizard.  One could use either the backup software which comes with Windows or some other backup wizard.

I believe the next step would be to restore the backup onto an external drive.  (The backup software in Windows creates a compressed file containing data.  To access the data, one has to restore the backup, or decompress the file.)

After installing Linux, I believe one would transfer the restored backup from the external drive to the hard drive, by using the "rsync" command.  I believe one would type, "rsync -r SRC DEST", where "SRC" is the location of the restored backup on the external drive, and "DEST" is the desired location for the file system on the computer.  I understand that the "-r" option copies directories recursively.  Since I would want all directories and subdirectories to be transferred to my computer, I believe I would need to use this option.

I read that the "rsync" command automatically performs a "checksum", to verify that copied data files are identical to originals.  So, I do not believe I would need to do anything extra to verify that all the data are transferred without errors.  Is that correct?

Since I would be transferring data from Windows files, and since "rsync" is a command used on Linux systems, I am a little bit concerned that something might go wrong when I use "rsync" for the transfer.  Is this an issue?  I would think that the automatic "checksum" run by "rsync" would ensure that there are no errors in the data transfer.  However, I thought I should ask.

After performing the desired data transfer, I understand that it might only be possible to read and modify certain data files with Windows applications.  I understand that such applications would have to be installed and operated with Wine on Linux.  However, my question is not about accessing data after a transfer.  My question is about how to correctly perform such a transfer.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why don't you just simply copy all your important personal files to an NTFS partition?  Your unlikely going to be able to use Windows applications, under Linux, and use the same application date you have been using.

Comment: There is no "Windows" data or "Linux" data, there are just files. Put them in a safe place on your hard drive (a simple Copy command is sufficient), and then install Linux. Linux can read and write any files Windows software can create. There's no need for any additional "transferring".

Comment: Rather than relying on a slow, file-by-file backup (that also might omit essential data!), make a *complete disk image* using third-party software such as free Macrium Reflect or an alternative. That way, even if data is lost during transition to Linux, everything can be restored... and, if you prefer to revert, you can go back to Windows, too.

Comment: @Ramhound I would prefer to have only one operating system on my computer, rather than two operating systems on a partitioned hard drive.  I was wondering whether the procedure I described would work for transferring data.  Would there be any risk of data loss?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik  I am planning to create a Windows rescue disk, so I can revert to Windows if necessary.   I created a Windows backup, and there were some warning messages about certain files not getting backed up.  However, I read through all the warning messages, and none of my data files failed to back up.  The warnings were about software files I am not planning to transfer to Linux.

Comment: @kreemoweet  I read that there is a danger of data loss when one performs a simple copy command.  I also read that it is important to have data saved on an external storage device when changing operating systems.  There could be a danger of losing everything if the data are only saved on the hard drive.

Comment: @CaspertheFriendlyGrue - Your idea is excessive if you are only transferring personal documents.  My suggestion of an NTFS partition involves no operating system it would only hold data, you make only a side mention of WINE, it's unclear which applications you're expecting to work with it. **WINE compatibility isn't infinite and honestly pretty limited**  If you need a Windows application my suggestion would be to use a VM.  Creating a "Windows Rescue" disk is pretty much pointless if you have installed Linux and WIndows isn't actually installed.

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you for your comment.  I am not sure I would even need Wine.  I mostly would be transferring Word documents.  In the past, I have been able to open Word documents with OpenOffice on Linux.  So, I might not need Word on Linux.  You said that a Windows rescue disk would be useless if I already have installed Linux.  I thought one could reinstall Windows from a rescue disk.  However, I am not sure whether the correct terminology is a "rescue disk" or a "recovery disk".  I was planning on creating a disk for reinstalling Windows if necessary.

Comment: @CaspertheFriendlyGrue, Windows rescue disks are of limited value; they do not contain the complete syste, nor personal files. The safe thing to do is make a complete disk image *before* making changes... afterwards is too late.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik  There is no software I wish to transfer over to Linux.  If I were to return to Windows, then I could easily reinstall the software I have added to my computer.  Given that I am backing up my personal data, I wonder whether I really need a full disk image.  I would think I could simply use a Windows rescue disk to reinstall Windows, and then import the backed up data.

Comment: To everyone: Once I have Linux installed, I was wondering whether the "rsync" command would provide a safe means of transferring data from a backup drive to my hard drive.  Would it matter that the files and directories in the backup were created in Windows?  I do not believe I would need Windows for opening and editing any of my data files.  My Windows data files are Microsoft Word Documents, and I think I should be able to open and edit these with OpenOffice.  I also believe I could use Wine or Crossover to install and operate Word on Linux.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Sorry if my questions and comments have been naive.  Are you saying that a Windows Rescue disk would not allow me to reinstall Windows after uninstalling the operating system?  Are you saying that a complete disk image would provide the only means of reinstalling Windows?  I think this is what you are trying to tell me, but I want to clarify this issue.  Thank you for your advice.  I appreciate it.

Comment: @CaspertheFriendlyGrue, it depends on the type of recovery media. Some original equipment manufacturer (OEM) media restores the PC to as-purchased -- the original version of Windows (*sans* updates), all the original trial and sample games and software, etc. For media created in Windows, see https://www.howtogeek.com/131907/how-to-create-and-use-a-recovery-drive-or-system-repair-disc-in-windows-8/ . That said, there have been times I've found the Windows system repair & system image could not bring the PC back to working order, but have never had an issue with a *full disk image*.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Thank you for the information. I plan to create a full disk image. As a second issue, I was wondering whether the rsync command would provide a safe means of loading data from a restored image, to a newly installed Linux system. Would it matter that the directories and files in the image were created in Windows? I do not think that should matter, but I thought I should ask.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I have one other question.  I am thinking about putting my disk image onto a Seagate external hard drive.  Seagate provides wizards for creating disk images and backups on their hard drives.  Do you know whether the external hard drives and wizards produced by Seagate are reliable?  I believe Seagate must be reliable, since the company is accredited by the Better Business Bureau, and has an A+ rating.  Nevertheless, I thought I would ask your opinion.  Once again, thank you for your help.

Comment: This site is not for product recommendations.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Okay, I understand that this site is not for product recommendations. Sorry for bothering you with my question about Seagate. However, I have one additional question. I was wondering whether the rsync command would provide a safe means of transferring Windows data from a restored disk image on an external drive, to a newly installed Linux system. As you know, rsync is a command for Linux systems. Would it matter that I would be using rsync to transfer data from Windows directories and files? I do not think it should matter, but I thought I should ask. Thank you for your help.